# How to find p-value for numeric paired variables

Tags: r, p-value, paired-data

I am comparing student exam score and happiness. For example, a student with a 98 on an exam rated their happiness a '9' on a scale of 1-10, and 200 student did the same thing. I am trying to find the p-value to see if these are correlated or not. Should I be using p-value? If so, how can I find it? If I should be using r^2 instead, what's a good way to find that?

Comment: Sounds like a you should use a F-Test for regression.

Comment: It sounds like you want statistical advise, not help with programming. You may want to ask on Cross Validated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "did the same thing"?  Do you mean 200+1 students all scored 98 and rated their happiness as 9?